# why fastapi swagger interface dont update after new code update at same port

Tags: fastapi, fastapi-crudrouter

fastapi swagger UI is showing the same interface of previous code.for example I had fastapi swagger ui using some html in code.but new code does not have html part.but it is showing the previous int interface even after removing DNS cache.

how to run new fast api swagger ui on same port 8000

Comment: Are you running `uvicorn` with `--reload`? Have you refreshed the /docs browser tab?

Comment: yes..uvicorn app:app --reload

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another port:

`uvicorn main:app --port 8001`